# Insert query as string in database on insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that will fire every time a new row is created in a table. When that happens, an insert query will be prepared that reflects how the row was inserted. This query will be stored to a table in another database.

To illustrate:

- Database A has table products (id, name, duration, isavailable).
- Database B has a table mysql_query (id, query)

When a new row (1001, 'test product', 365, 1) is inserted into A.products, the trigger should insert the following into B.mysql_query:

```
INSERT INTO products (id, name, duration, value, isavailable) 
VALUES (1001, test product, 365, 1, 1)
```

Value by default will always be 1 for the moment.

The code for the trigger so far is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER c_products
ON migrimi_test.dbo.products
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @c_id INT;
    SET @c_id = (SELECT id from inserted);

    DECLARE @c_name INT;
    SET @c_name = (SELECT name from inserted);

    DECLARE @c_duration INT;
    SET @c_duration = (SELECT duration from inserted);

    DECLARE @c_isavailable INT;
    SET @c_isavailable = (SELECT isvisible from inserted);
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO migrimi_temp.dbo.mysql_query (id, mysql_query)
    VALUES (DEFAULT, 'INSERT INTO products (id, name, duration, value, isavailable) values ('+CAST(@c_id as nvarchar(50))+', '+'"'+@c_name'+'"'+, '+@c_duration+', 1, '+@c_isavailable+')' )
END
GO
```

I run the trigger and latter perform an insert. There is an error saying:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test product' to data type int.

I understand that it refers to the substitution of variable `@c_name` but this is the first trigger I ever write, and I can't tell what exactly is wrong.

A and B are SQL databases.

Comment: `DECLARE @c_name INT;  SET @c_name = (SELECT name from inserted);` name is nvarchar... change `@c_name` to nvarchar datatype.

Comment: Also, you can use one `Select` statement. `Select @c_id = id, @c_name = name, @c_duration = duration, @c_isavailable = isvisible from inserted`

Comment: @WEI_DBA: you were right, I was declaring the variable c_name as int even though it is a string (nvarchar in my case). Also I had another error. that will be reflected in the update of the question. But I am still getting an error similar to this.

Comment: Post your updated query and the error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there were 3 problems with the trigger:

1- As WEI_DBA pointed out, @c_name was declared int, even though it was in fact an varchar.

2- Apparently every int variable should be cast as a varchar or it will throw the following error:

> sql trigger Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to
>   datatype int

I still don't have this figured out 100% - this is the solution but I am googling the reason why. So don't take my word for granted and feel free to provide more reliable sources or alternative explanations / solutions. After all I am a trigger newbie.

3- While the trigger itself will work, the query inserted in the table mysql_query will be invalid unless the value @c_name (or any varchar value) is surrounded by double quotes.

The final result of a working trigger is the following:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER c_products
ON migrimi_test.dbo.products
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @c_id INT;
    DECLARE @c_name nvarchar(100);
    DECLARE @c_duration int;
    DECLARE @c_isavailable INT;
    Select @c_id = id, @c_name = name, @c_duration = duration, @c_isavailable = isvisible from inserted

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO migrimi_temp.dbo.sql_query (query)
    VALUES ('INSERT INTO products (id, name, duration, value, isavailable, createdAt, updatedAt) values ('+CAST(@c_id as nvarchar(50))+', '+'"'+@c_name+'"'+', 
    '+CAST(@c_duration as nvarchar(50))+', 1, '+CAST(@c_isavailable as nvarchar(50))+', Now(), Now());' )
END
GO
```

Ignore the new fields, there were modifications that I made but have nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: This solution will work for single row inserts, but not for multiple inserts